# Specifying memory address for labels

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

Is it possible to change or modify the address of a label in MIPS? (I am using MARS)

for example...

```
.data
x: .half 9
```

now that 'x' will be stored randomly in memory, but what if i wanted to store it in specific address? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the address after the `.data`

For example, if you want to store x in the address 0x2000 you should write

```
.data 0x2000
.half 9
```